# onTouchEvent is not called when talkback enabled on custom view

Tags: android, talkback

I'm implementing custom keyboard (through custom view) for password field and trying add accessibility feature, so when user single press on view it should pronounce selected value.

In my custom keyboard I need coordinates from `MotionEvent` so view can calculate on what draw (value) it was pressed.

But in this case when Talkback enabled `onTouchEvent` method is not called. It calls only when user double tap on view. Im trying to add custom `OnTouchListener` but it does not work. `setFocusable=true` and `setFocusableInTouchMode=true`.

Comment: what is "Talkback enabled" ?

Comment: enabled in android settings

Comment: did you try to override dispatchTouchEvent ad add some Log.d statements?

Comment: empty log for `dispatchTouchEvent`

Comment: @aim I think exact answer to your question is in my answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When TalkBack is enabled a double tap is the equivalent of a single tap. That is, onTouchEvent will only be called when the user double taps a view/widget.

Answer (score 10):

For those that come across this question and looking for a solution; 
When accessibility (Talkback) is enabled, `onTouchEvent` method is not called on single tap, it's called on double taps instead.

To catch single taps when accessibility is enabled, and/or override this behaviour, `onHoverEvent` method of `View` class should be overriden. By using this method, you can catch single touch **down** as `ACTION_HOVER_ENTER`, **move** as `ACTION_HOVER_MOVE` and **up** as `ACTION_HOVER_EXIT`.

Also you can override this behaviour by modifying the action of caught `MotionEvent` and sending it to `onTouchEvent` method as shown below:

```
@Override
public boolean onHoverEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (accessibilityManager.isTouchExplorationEnabled() && event.getPointerCount() == 1) {
        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER: {
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
            } break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE: {
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
            } break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT: {
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
            } break;
        }
        return onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return true;
}
```