# Detect Multitouch programmatically when TalkBack is enable

Tags: android, multi-touch, talkback

I developing a app for blinds and I need to detect number of points that tap on screen when the TalkBack is ON. (when isTouchExplorationEnabled is true). How do I do that?

Tried code so far:

```
private class MytempClass extends View {
        Context context;

    public MytempClass(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onHoverEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //Move AccessibilityManager object to the constructor
        AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
        if (am.isTouchExplorationEnabled()) {
            return onTouchEvent(event);
        } else {
            return super.onHoverEvent(event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = event.getPointerCount();

        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, event.getX() + "- num of points" + x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
                //code
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
                //code
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489714/ontouchevent-is-not-called-when-talkback-enabled-on-custom-view